# Not able to send Ether to contract

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, truffle, ether, contract-debugging

I am trying to send Ethers to a contract deployed on Ganache but I am getting  `VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`, the same logic is able to transfer Ethers to other account.

Following are error log and the code for sending Ether

**Code:**
*Fallback method:*

```
function() public payable {
    transfer(msg.sender, msg.value);
}
```

*Transfer logic:*

```
/**
* @dev Transfer token for a specified address
* @param _to The address to transfer to.
* @param _value The amount to be transferred.
*/
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);
    require(_to != address(0));

    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
}
```

**Error:**

```
Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
    at Object.ErrorResponse (errors.js:29)
    at index.js:140
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (index.js:79)
    at XMLHttpRequest.push../node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request-event-target.js.XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (xml-http-request-event-target.js:34)
    at XMLHttpRequest.push../node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js.XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (xml-http-request.js:208)
    at XMLHttpRequest.push../node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js.XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (xml-http-request.js:318)
    at push../node_modules/stream-http/lib/response.js.exports.IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (xml-http-request.js:289)
    at push../node_modules/stream-http/lib/response.js.exports.IncomingMessage.push../node_modules/events/events.js.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1010)
    at afterTickTwo (index.js:27)
    at Object.ErrorResponse (errors.js:29)
    at index.js:140
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (index.js:79)
    at XMLHttpRequest.push../node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request-event-target.js.XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (xml-http-request-event-target.js:34)
    at XMLHttpRequest.push../node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js.XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (xml-http-request.js:208)
    at XMLHttpRequest.push../node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js.XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (xml-http-request.js:318)
    at push../node_modules/stream-http/lib/response.js.exports.IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (xml-http-request.js:289)
    at push../node_modules/stream-http/lib/response.js.exports.IncomingMessage.push../node_modules/events/events.js.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1010)
    at afterTickTwo (index.js:27)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
    at zone.js:724
    at index.js:72
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3815)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:496)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:485)
    at timer (zone.js:2054)
```

Comment: Does `msg.sender` have enough balance?

Comment: Yes, the accounts have the appropriate balance.

Comment: @Paradox We're going to need more proof. :-) The transaction is being reverted, and there's only one relevant `require`, so my assumption is that `msg.value >  balances[msg.sender]`. (To verify, remove that `require` statement and try again.)

Comment: How are you sending the Ether? From another smart contract using `address.transfer` by any chance? Because in that case, the gas stipend that is sent along with the call is not going to be enough for all these computations and storage operations

Comment: @Paradox Sorry, just removing that `require` won't be enough, because it's already redundant. (I'm assuming `.sub(...)` is some sort of "safe math" routine that reverts when the result underflows.) Maybe just add `balances[msg.sender] = 2**256-1` instead to verify the balance is the issue.

Comment: @smarx I don't know how but restarting the computer fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know its kinda funny but restarting the machine fixed the issue XD.